# Shortest distance between random points on a circle?

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization

I am trying to test the accuracy of a few optimization algorithms on the traveling salesman problem.

I wanted to create a system where I always knew what the optimal solution is. My logic was that I would create a bunch of random points on a unit circle and thus would always know the shortest path because it would just be the order of the points on the circle. And how would I find the order? Well, just iterate through each point and find its closest neighbor. It turns out that it works most of the time, but sometimes... It doesn't!

[image]
**Are there any suggestions for an algorithm that would find the optimal solution of random points on a unit circle 100% of the time?** I like being able to just randomly create points on the circle.

Comment: Just curious, why did you choose a circle over something simpler like a straight line or a triangle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compute a 100% accurate solution using a [convex hull algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms). This solution will be exact as long as the optimal TSP path is convex, which is the case for a simple circle. The [monotone chain](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Geometry/Convex_hull/Monotone_chain#Python) algorithm is very interesting because it is both very fast and trivial to understand (not to mention that the implementation is also provided by Wikipedia in many languages).

Answer (score 0):

[Jérôme Richard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67247163/47984) works for this case and for all cases involving points on the boundary of a convex polygon, but there is an even simpler algorithm that also works for all these cases: For each point, just find the angle that a line through that point and the circle centre makes with a horizontal line through the circle centre, and sort the points by that.

If the origin (0, 0) is inside your circle, and your language has the [`atan2() function`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) (most do -- it's a standard trig function), you can just apply `atan2()` to each point and sort them by that.